# When I build from unity to Xcode a calculation doesn't happen properly

Tags: unity, c#, xcode

I am building an app which calculates the elevation and azimuth of 2 points using latitude, longitude and elevation. I have built it and run it on Xcode and the azimuth is locked on either 270º or 90º. I think it may be Xcode doesn't know how to use `Math.Atan()` can anyone confirm this.

this is my code

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using System;

public class SatelliteCoordinates1 : MonoBehaviour {
    public float personLat;
    public float personLon;
    public float personElv;
    public float satLat;
    public float satLon;
    public float satElv;
    public Text personLatText;
    public Text personLonText;
    public Text personElvText;
    public Text satLatText;
    public Text satLonText;
    public Text satElvText;
    public Text elevationOutput;
    public Text azimuthOutput;

    protected int radiusOfEarth = 6371000;

    public Vector3 PosInCartesian(float satLat, float satLon, float satElv)
    {
        float x;
        float y;
        float z;
        float satLatR = DegreesToRadians(satLat);
        float satLonR = DegreesToRadians(satLon);
        satElv = satElv+radiusOfEarth;

        x = (float)(Math.Cos(satLatR) * Math.Cos(satLonR) * satElv);
        y = (float)(Math.Cos(satLatR) * Math.Sin(satLonR) * satElv);
        z = (float)(Math.Sin(satLatR) * satElv);

        return new Vector3(x, y, z);

    }

    public float DegreesToRadians(float degrees)
    {
        return (float)(degrees * Math.PI / 180);
    }

    public float RadiansToDegrees(float radians)
    {
        return (float)(radians * 180 / Math.PI);
    }
    public double RadiansToDegreesD(double radians)
    {
        return (radians * 180 / Math.PI);
    }
    public float FindElevation(Vector3 Pos1, Vector3 Pos2)
    {
        float dx = Pos2.x - Pos1.x;
        float dy = Pos2.y - Pos1.y;
        float dz = Pos2.z - Pos1.z;

        float x = (int)Pos1.x;
        float y = (int)Pos1.y;
        float z = (int)Pos1.z;

        float cosElv = (float)((x * dx + y * dy + z * dz) / Math.Sqrt((Math.Pow(x,2) + Math.Pow(y,2) + Math.Pow(z,2)) * (Math.Pow(dx,2) + Math.Pow(dy,2) + Math.Pow(dz,2))));
        float elvR = (float)Math.Acos(cosElv);
        float elv = RadiansToDegrees(elvR);
        float elvToReturn = (90f - elv);
        return elvToReturn;

    }

    public Vector3 FindNorthVector(Vector3 Pos1)
    {
        float x = Pos1.x;
        float y = Pos1.y;
        float z = Pos1.z;
        float newZ = (float)(Math.Pow(x, 2) + Math.Pow(y, 2));
        Vector3 northVector = new Vector3(-z * x, -z * y, newZ);
        return northVector;
    }

    public float FindCosAzimuth(Vector3 satPos1, Vector3 satPos2)
    { 
        float x = satPos1.x;
        float y = satPos1.y;
        float z = satPos1.z;

        float dx = satPos2.x - satPos1.x;
        float dy = satPos2.y - satPos1.y;
        float dz = satPos2.z - satPos1.z;
        float cosAzi = (float)((-z * x * dx - z * y * dy + (x * x + y * y) * dz) / Math.Sqrt(((x * x) + (y * y))*(x * x + y * y + z * z)*(dx * dx + dy * dy + dz * dz)));
        return cosAzi;
    }

    public float FindSinAzimuth(Vector3 satPos1, Vector3 satPos2)
    {
        float x = satPos1.x;
        float y = satPos1.y;

        float dx = satPos2.x - satPos1.x;
        float dy = satPos2.y - satPos1.y;
        float dz = satPos2.z - satPos1.z;

        //float sinAzi = (float)((-y * dx + x * dy) / (Math.Sqrt((x * x + y * y) * (dx * dx + dy * dy + dz * dz))));
        float sinAzi = (float)((-y * dx + x * dy) / (Math.Sqrt((x * x + y * y) * (dx * dx + dy * dy + dz * dz))));
        return sinAzi;
    }

    public float ToBearing(float result)
{

    if (result < 0)
    {
        result = 360 + result;
    }


    return result;
}

public float FindAzimuth(Vector3 satPos1, Vector3 satPos2)
{
    float cosAzi = FindCosAzimuth(satPos1, satPos2);
    float sinAzi = FindSinAzimuth(satPos1, satPos2);
    float aziR = (float)Math.Atan2(sinAzi, cosAzi);
    float azi = RadiansToDegrees(aziR);
    azi = ToBearing(azi);
    return azi;

    }

    private void Start()
    {
        print("Print Works");
    }

    public void WhenButtonIsPressed()
    {

        personLat = float.Parse(personLatText.text);
        personLon = float.Parse(personLonText.text);
        personElv = float.Parse(personElvText.text);
        satLat = float.Parse(satLatText.text);
        satLon = float.Parse(satLonText.text);
        satElv = float.Parse(satElvText.text);
        Vector3 personPos = PosInCartesian(personLat, personLon, personElv);
        Vector3 satPos = PosInCartesian(satLat, satLon, satElv);
        float elevation = FindElevation(personPos, satPos);
        float azimuth = FindAzimuth(personPos, satPos);
        elevation = (float)(Math.Round(elevation, 5));
        azimuth = (float)(Math.Round(azimuth, 5));
        elevationOutput.text = elevation.ToString();
        azimuthOutput.text = azimuth.ToString();
        print("azimuth calculated");





    }



}
```

Comment: `Math.ATan()`'s behavior is not controlled by XCode

Comment: I mean in unity I use Math.ATan() but when I build to Xcode i don't think it carries across

Comment: One thing I note right away is that you're passing `cosAzi` before `sinAzi` in the call to `Atan2`, while it seems that you'd want to pass them in the opposite order. It's signature is `double Atan2(double y, double x)`. Ah, and that would explain why you currently need that call to `FromEastToNorthBearing` in there.

Comment: OK, I got curious and copied your code into a project. The generated C++ code for `Math.Atan2` is regular old `atan2`. That seems likely to be correct!

Comment: Re. Victor T. Thanks for catching that i have changed code accordingly

Comment: Re. Victor (second post) Ok but why then would it only give me 270 or 90 in Xcode when in unity it gives me the correct numbers

Comment: You'd get those values if you passed it an x value of zero. Is it possible the problem isn't in Atan2, but in the calculation of one of its inputs?

Comment: I just don’t understand why it would work in unity and the android emulator but not Xcode